# Android "Best" way to implement button callbacks (XML onClick, New onClickListener, implement onClickListener, seperate class for that button)

Tags: android, coding-style, android-fragments, android-activity

Do read this in full before you assume it is a poll, I am seeking info and references to make an informed decision not trying to determine which is the most popular ( @PéterVarga )

This is my first question here guys, I've finally registered because I've popped in so many times I felt I was actually making it worse for myself. This question is quite open ended yes because I want the pros and cons. 
I've tried to EMBRACE Android and how it does things (XML, Activities, destroying Activities) stuff like that, and normally I'm a WxWidgets man so this feels very different. The more I read the more it makes sense. But there is one question, this question, which applies not just to buttons but all callbacks. Android Tutorials and guides so far seem to be (MOSTLY) more about getting something running quick, as I said, I seek to embrace Android, not make yet another tat app for it.

So as the title suggests I've used buttons for this, but yes, any callback.

First usage case "Question"
Consider 2 Fragments, A and B, and 2 Activities, X and Y.
Lets now say A contains a list, and B the details for an item on that list (a generic setup)
If in Landscape mode Activity X will display both Fragments, A and B, if in portrait mode, if nothing is selected (and the selection stored via whatever means (feel free to mention potential/decent ways) Fragment A will be shown by X, when something is selected (or if something was selected) Fragment B will be shown by Activity Y.
If it is in landscape mode, Activity Y will have it's "finish()" method called, which I understand commences it's destruction. I could verify this empirically but this means my conclusions would be inferred from the behaviour rather than (although I may deduce correctly) what Google actually intended.

If I use the XML onClick method, B will sometimes get that callback, if it is finished, how can it, will it go to A instead?
Should I add the logic to the fragment? (by making a new onClickListener inline)
Should I instead do what I'd probably do in WxWidgets, where I extend a class for basically everything and have my own class for the button, which implements onClickListener and hence can have it's own onClick method?

If it helps in my homework I have learned that I probably shouldn't try and catch the config change events, I accept that my Activies will be closed and restarted, so I can in the onCreate methods check the orientation because for the lifecycle of the activity it won't be changing orientation.
Which leads to my final question, is Bundle the only way? I found another, but it was deprecated and only for config changes.

Thanks, sorry it's long and yes, quite broad. I truly cannot find a debate on this anywhere.
(In the post today arrived the O'Reilly Android book, I suspect that they (O'Reilly books) are popular here, please give me a page reference or even what this is all called if you know. The Wrox Android 4 Dev. book also arrived I had this as a PDF and to show my approval, purchased it, again, subject title please this is 4th edition (or just 4) so I have yet to read the Fragments section but I doubt that'll shed much light)

BTW, I can see the similar questions down the side and I been reading them when I click post on this, if I do, it is because I still see this as a question.

Edit 1: (Edits being updates rather than clarifications, new parts basically)
For anyone who reads this (1's are in page 250 of unanswered Q's, with 50 per page....) I'll post my thoughts so you may be able to get an answer (if I don't)
I've decided to try something like this:

```
this.MemberOfClass = 0;
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MemberOfClass++;        
        MethodOfClass();
    }
});
```

Where (I used "this" to illustrate what I mean by MemberOfClass) MethodOfClass is not a method of OnClickListener but of the class this occurs in (Not sure if I love or hate Java's scoping), this creates a way to have multiple buttons per Fragment (or Activity) with control of exactly which MethodOfClass gets called (Activity X's or Y's to follow my own example) based on where exactly this code is located.

It seems VERY wasteful to create an object on a platform which really values tiny memory footprints and fine-for-use-on-low-spec-systems software, but I have not found a better way, hence this question.

Edit 2:
I'm looking into how I'd go about creating a separate button class for each button while still keeping the XML part tidy (using the button primitive)

Comment: A separate class is probably overkill, but all options work. Which is the best? Depends on the specific use case. Stackoverflow is not for polls.

Comment: Please read the posts in full before responding, the question isn't saying "vote for your fav. way" Please clarify what usage cases a separate class would work? How could I use one class? THIS IS THE POINT OF THE QUESTION. @PéterVarga It is really disheartening to see stuff downvoted because someone didn't read the question on day 1. As if that first question would be a poll, please.

Answer (score 1):

Look, when you specify XML onClick attribute with callback method name, it would try to find specified method within a Context currently holding your fragment. In this case it's great to separate your view description (XML layout) from functionality logics. So I'd personnaly like to implement different on click listeners for every fragment (no matter whether you declare them as anonymous classes or separate ones).

You can create your own class for each button, but I'm afraid it's not very good idea from object-oriented paradigm POV. Usually the reason to create new class is to generalize some commonly used entity (which consists of instances multitude). In the situation beeing discussed your button would be probably specific to some action only, so it's not necessary to create new class for each action type.

There's also a way to determine which Activity has called your listener's onClick method. Somewhere inside onClick() just call view.getContext() of supplied view argument and check it's class with instanceof operator on if it is either ActivityA instance or ActivityB instance.

In addition, may suggest you to try sticking to Java coding conventions and not to name class fields and methods starting with capital. It just helps other people to read and understand your code faster and clearer.

Answer (score 0):

`Anonymous Class` is the way to go since the most of the cases you would need only `one instance` so it would be a waste to make a separate class and implement OnClickListener, as a good practice i like to create this anonymous objects in a `method` because it is more easy to read `createRequestItemPositiveListner()` than in a method that creates a `Dialog` like this:

```
dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            //do request item things...
        }
    });
```

i preffer this:

```
dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", createRequestItemPositiveListener());
```

is more easy to read and if you want to look up for the code done in the "PositiveButton" of the Dialog is more easy by the method than in a piece of code somewhere in the Dialog creation, things get worse if `request item things` require at least 30-50 lines of code, the Dialog creation would turn into a mess, i recommend you to read `Clean Code` book of `Uncle-Bob (Robert C. Martin)` for a better understanding.